# DataBind() on Gridview slow

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have an application using a gridview that is really slow.

After adding the `Trace=true` for the page, I tracked down where time is spent: when calling BindData() on a GridView. The `GridView` is connected to a `LinqDataSource`.

Here is the trace output:

```
GetContact        0.955485090710761        0.000339
  DataBind        0.97438854173692         0.018903
  PopulateStates  6.58986882347249         5.615480
```

Here is the sample asp.net page

```
<asp:LinqDataSource ContextTypeName="DAL.BALDataContext" TableName="loc_access_contacts"
    ID="_ldsContact" runat="server" OrderBy="organisation, last_name, first_name">
</asp:LinqDataSource>
<cc1:CustomGridView ID="gvContact" runat="server" DataSourceID="_ldsContact" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Width="100%"
    DataKeyNames="person_id" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" AllowPaging="False"
    AllowSorting="True" BorderStyle="None" ShowFooter="false" CaptionAlign="Top"
    PagerStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" HeaderStayPolicy="NotStay" SessionKey="Contact.GridView.Columns.SortSettings"
    SaveKey="ContactManagementSortSettings" OnRowCommand="gvContact_RowCommand" OnSorting="gvContact_Sorting">
```

In Code Behind:

```
Trace.Write("  DataBind");
gvContact.DataBind();

Trace.Write("  PopulateStates");
populateStates(contact);
```

The LINQ Data Source code looks like:

```
public System.Data.Linq.Table<loc_access_contact> loc_access_contacts
{
  get
  {
    return this.GetTable<loc_access_contact>();
  }
}
```

The SQL generated from this property is a canonical `SELECT <all fields> FROM loc_access_contact`.

And the table `loc_access_contact` looks like :

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[loc_access_contact](
[person_id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[organisation] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[last_name] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[first_name] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[is_active] [tinyint] NULL,
[state_id] [char](2) NULL,
[postal_code] [nchar](4) NULL,
[town] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
[phone_number] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
[mobile_number] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
[fax_number] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
[email_address] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
[street_name] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
[house_number] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
[postal_box] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
[language] [tinyint] NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_person] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[person_id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

The table contains about 287 contacts.

How come the DataBind is so slow ? How can I track further down what is happening ?

Comment: Maybe some property in source evaluates slow?

Comment: I have added some information regarding the source, but I still don't see why it is so slow ? The table has currently 287 entries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using SQL Server - I would put a trace on the application then run again. Then I would pick out the actual SQL that is been run. Run that directly on the database then see if you can spot bottlenecks.

It looks as if you are bringing back all the data in `loc_access_contacts` so it could be the sheer volume of data.

Another possibly is the sorting. You are sorting by organisation, last_name, first_name. I would be tempted to put a non-clustered index on these columns to help with the sort efficient. Do check though that this table has a sensible clustered index i.e. primary key.

Of course I'm assuming here that you have control over your DB which I know a lot of people don't. In that case (or honestly in every case) use paging in your grid. If you can use some kind of sensible server side paging (i.e. by using `Skip` and `Take` LINQ operators) this will greatly improve your bind efficient. They will be simply a lot less data.

Comment: Use SQL profiler to see how the query get executed on the database side.

Comment: absolutely - sorry i didn't name it. Use SQL Profiler

Comment: The query is a canonical SELECT <fields> FROM <table>. There are 287 entries currently in the DB.

Comment: Regarding the sorting, I removed the order clause. This does not make any difference.

Comment: Is the select <fields> from <table> SQL quick when ran direct against the DB? Is there something ver wrong with the database? Can you get onto the box. Is the CPU maxed out/out of memory etc.. i.e. does the box look well? I would change the query temporarily to SELECT TOP 10 <fields> FROM <table> just to sanity check it all. There is something a bit odd going on

Comment: I would also look at server side paging while you are at it though - http://www.jonathanjungman.com/blog/post/Custom-Paging-with-LINQ.aspx. The link also gives how to hook into linq statement and do the select top 10 etc..... Also check the tables primary key. I would update statistics on the table and rebuild the indexes. Could improve

Comment: After running the SQL Profiler, the query takes around 0.01s to execute. Everything run on my local brand new i7 PC with 8Mb RAM (4Mb seems to be used) and SSD drive. Everything should fly !

Comment: The explication I suspect now is in the generation of the GridView content. For each entry (287 in total) I have 14 ButtonField definitions. This leads to massive HTML generation ~600K. If I add a simple AllowPaging="true" to the GridView, the performance is much better.

Answer (score -1):

I Suffered from the same problem ,
But when I tried a simple trick solved it

I just replaced (`Select * From TableName`) By (`Select Top [Num] * From TableName` )

** Replace Num with the max records you expect in result .

And It makes a huge difference,

Comment: The table contains 287 records. How limiting to 100000 top records could fix the problem?

Comment: @Raeisi I edited my answer 
What I mean is that The Top Number solved the problem I used Top 1,000,000 , and my table contains less than 6,000 records, but I considered the future increase in records

Comment: That doesn't make sense. A `TOP` statement is not going to reduce data if there are less records than the topped number. For this question it's not an answer anyway. Also, the accepted answer already mentions "volume of data".

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Actually the problem come back again , I traced the SQL Stored procedure  
and  discovered that a sql parameter @SearchKeyWord that I do  LTrim and RTrim on it   and didn't pass string  to it from the asp.net form and it has no default value  was causing the problem